# Jar file won't open

Tags: macos, java, osx-yosemite

Running a mac with yosemite. I have a load calc software that won't open. I keep getting this error.

The Java Jar file "file_name.jar" could not be launched. Check the console for possible messages.

So I checked the console and found this message:

```
1/27/15 3:37:09.807 PM java[807]: objc[807]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/./libjli.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

What do I do to specify which of them it is to use? I have checked and made sure that java is up to date and so is the program.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command like this 
`java -jar file_name.jar path.to.JavaLaunchHelper`

path.to.JavaLaunchHelper should be replaced with the either of the below things you mentioned

/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/./libjli.dylib